# Can I find $|A \cap B \cap C|$ if I know $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$, $|A \cap B|$, $|A \cap C|$, and $|B \cap C|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have aggregated values of the number of elements in sets $A$, $B$, and $C$. I know the number of elements intersecting $A \cap B$, $A \cap C$, and $B \cap C$.

I do not know the union of the three sets: $A \cup B \cup C$

The question is if I can determine number of elements in $A \cap B \cap C$ using this information?

Comment: Do you also know the number of elements in total ($A\cup B\cup C$)?

Comment: That's the challenge is that I do not know the union of all three sets.

Comment: The answer is "no" and it is easy to come up with examples showing that $|A\cap B\cap C|$ can be empty and can contain one element with the same numbers $|A|, |B|, |C|, |A\cap B|, ...$.

Comment: @markvs You beat me to it.  I just found a simple example which only uses counts of 0 and 1.

Comment: It will depend on the exact data.  The given answers show there are some data for which the answer is not determined.  But for a trivial example, if you know that $|A \cap B| = 0$, then of course you also know $|A \cap B \cap C|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Let,  $A=\{1,2,4\}, B=\{2,3,4\}, C=\{3,1,4\}$ so that $|A|=|B|=|C|=3$, $|A\cap B|=|B\cap C|=|C\cap A|=2$ and $|A\cap B\cap C|=1$

Now, let,  $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{1,2,4\}, C=\{1,2,5\}$ so that $|A|=|B|=|C|=3$, $|A\cap B|=|B\cap C|=|C\cap A|=2$ and $|A\cap B\cap C|=2$

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Let me give you a counterexample. Suppose $|A|=|B|=|C|=3$, $|A\cap B|=|B\cap C|=1$ and $|A\cap C|=2$. Then there are a bunch of possibilities that meet these conditions, but we are only interested in two of them. Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $C=\{1,2,4\}$. Then both $B=\{1,5,6 \}$ and $B=\{3,4,5 \}$ meet the initial conditions. With the first $B$, we have that $|A\cap B\cap C|=1$ and with the second one $|A\cap B\cap C|=0$.